# Wrapping with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, svg, nokogiri

I apologize if this has been answered, but I can't find the correct way to get this working.  I'm using Nokogiri to modify SVG diagrams that are generated through an application and I hit a bit of a snag.  The code I'm working with looks something like this:

```
<svg>
    <g id="1">
        <text>lorem</text>
        <text>ipsum</text>
    </g>
    <g id="2">
        <text>lorem</text>
        <text>ipsum</text>
    </g>
    <g id="3">
        <text>lorem</text>
        <text>ipsum</text>
    </g>
<svg>
```

I'd like to have this appended to every document as it is analyzed by the script:

```
<svg>
  <g id="scale" transform="scale(1.0)">
    <g id="1">
        <text>lorem</text>
        <text>ipsum</text>
    </g>
    <g id="2">
        <text>lorem</text>
        <text>ipsum</text>
    </g>
    <g id="3">
        <text>lorem</text>
        <text>ipsum</text>
    </g>
   </g>
<svg>
```

I've tried using methods such as before and after but it won't work correctly in this situation.  Ideally I'd just wrap the entirety of the nodeset with wrap, but I can't figure out how to get it to work across all sets rather than on every nodeset.  Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like your closing `svg` tags are missing the slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<svg>
    <g id="1">
        <text>lorem</text>
        <text>ipsum</text>
    </g>
    <g id="2">
        <text>lorem</text>
        <text>ipsum</text>
    </g>
    <g id="3">
        <text>lorem</text>
        <text>ipsum</text>
    </g>
</svg>
EOT

svg = doc.at('svg')
svg.children = '<g id="scale" transform="scale(1.0)">' + svg.children.to_xml + '</g>'
puts svg.to_xml
```

Running that outputs:

```
<svg>
  <g id="scale" transform="scale(1.0)">
    <g id="1">
        <text>lorem</text>
        <text>ipsum</text>
    </g>
    <g id="2">
        <text>lorem</text>
        <text>ipsum</text>
    </g>
    <g id="3">
        <text>lorem</text>
        <text>ipsum</text>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Nokogiri nicely lets us define nodes as strings, and coerces them to `XML::Node` objects. Give it a string containing XML and it'll convert it into a NodeSet, so we can cleanly and clearly manipulate the XML DOM without having to write u-gly code.

Answer (score 0):

```
doc = Nokogiri.XML( raw_svg )
wrapper_g = doc.create_element('g', 'id' => "scale", 'transform' => "scale(1.0)")
doc.xpath('/svg/g').each {|elem| wrapper_g << elem }
doc.root << wrapper_g
```

Optional - remove empty text nodes:

```
doc.xpath('//text()').each {|t| t.text =~ /\A\s*\z/ and t.remove }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [cheat sheet](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/Cheat-sheet) might help.

```rb
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(%Q{
<svg>
    <g id="1">
        <text>lorem</text>
        <text>ipsum</text>
    </g>
    <g id="2">
        <text>lorem</text>
        <text>ipsum</text>
    </g>
    <g id="3">
        <text>lorem</text>
        <text>ipsum</text>
    </g>
</svg>
})

svg = doc.xpath('//svg')[0]
wrapper = doc.create_element('g', 'id' => 'scale', 'transform' => 'scale(1.0)')
wrapper.children = svg.children
svg.add_child wrapper

puts doc
```

Note that you missed the slash at the closing `svg` tag.

Comment: Don't use `doc.xpath('//svg')[0]`. Instead use `at`  which is better for readability (or `at_xpath` if you want to be picky).

Comment: Thanks for the response and the link.  I'm definitely going reference this moving forward.